# Data Pre-Processing and cleaning in R

Tags: r, data-management, data-cleaning

I have a column `Expected_Stipend` in my data set as follows

```
Expected_Stipend<-c("5-10K","10k+","No Expectations")
```

I want to clean up `k` , `+` and  want to replace `No expectations` and i want to convert this column to numeric column using `R`?

The original data has many entries .

Comment: What is the expected output?  There is also `-` in `5-10K`

Comment: Not sure about your expected output.  If you want `5-10K` to become `510`, then `as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", Expected_Stipend))#[1] 510  10  NA`

Comment: No i dont want 5-10 become 510 i rather want to replace it by the median of 5 to 10

Comment: I posted a solution, please check.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract_all` from `library(stringr)` to extract all the numeric elements and get the `median`

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(Expected_Stipend, '\\d+'), 
              function(x) median(as.numeric(x)))
#[1]  7.5 10.0   NA
```

---

Or using `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]+", "",
  gsubfn("([0-9]+)[^0-9]+([0-9]+).*", ~median(as.numeric(c(x,y))),
                  Expected_Stipend)))
#[1]  7.5 10.0   NA
```

#### Update

if we need to replace `5-10K` by `5`

```
as.numeric(sub("^\\D*(\\d+).*", "\\1", Expected_Stipend))
#[1]  5 10 NA
```

Comment: great...thanku...one more question what if i want to replace 5-7 by 5